# DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching error throwing in IE after accessing tomcat hosted application via nginx

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, nginx

I have hosted my application in tomcat and configure reverse proxy in **nginx server** to access my application via https. 
It is working properly for Chrome and Mozilla. **But In IE i can see warning as  DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward.** And UI of application is also breaking.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem in IE with my nginx hosted apache application